# With latest Android sdks, is there still a Google Apis build target for Android 1.5?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm configuring a new machine for Android development and moving my current project over. I did a fresh install of all the Android tools and SDKs, and under "build targets", the Google APIs' target supports Android 2.2.

Of course I need 1.5 as the base build target. My project doesn't build when I select that because the Google Maps stuff from maps.jar isn't there. In fact, after I did my full install I can't find maps.jar anywhere on my new machine. Is this jar file still required for Google Maps integration, or is it history? I'm using Eclipse 3.5.

I guess I'd presume there would be a "google apis" for Android 1.5 build target. I'm thinking my install must be hosed; but maybe it's my understanding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. 1.5 is available.

When you open `SDK Setup.exe` it lists down 1.5, 1.6, 2.1 with 2.2. 
While in Eclipse you might need to set target explicitly.

[image]